# Angular + Yarn Workspace?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

My company has a yarn workspace setup. All the projects are in:
`<root>/projects/` and is setup correctly in the workspaces field in package.json of the `<root>`..yarnrc.yml has node-linker settings in it and node-modules is in `<root>/node-modules`. I want to add an Angular Universal project with @nestjs/ng-universal package to `<root>/projects/`. I added the angular files to the said directory skipping the install of packages. I tried to install the packages from  and tried running angular using yarn start in `<root>/projects/new-proj/` but its showing me that ajv-templates not found. I tried to ng add @nest/ng-universal...no luck... How do I solve this exact problem? I don't want to install node modules inside the angular project. I want it outside, common to all.